# How to implement In-App Purchases Subscription in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I want to provide auto renewable subscription in my Flutter App for both iOS and Android devices. Users can subscribe for 1 Month.

There is not an officially maintained in-app purchase plugin yet. But there are lots of plugins about In-App Purchases in Flutter.

Which one is the best? How to implement? Are these secure?

Comment: I haven't done any development myself with flutter, but I'm looking deep into it. Have you seen this plug-in yet? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_iap.  It seems like it can do In-App purchases as well as subscriptions. I'm curious about this too, so I'd like to know how it turns out! I'm going to start development soon.

Comment: As of July 2019, there seems to be official in-app purchase support plugin supported by google/flutter team. https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/in_app_purchase

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> ==== UPDATE from 11.03.2020
>
> Hi, I can see this post still reading by people who looking for a
> method of how to work with subscription in Flutter. During 2019 I made
> two apps with thousands install where users can buy a renewable
> subscription on the 2 platforms. Until February 2020 I used for this
> package from Flutter team https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase,
> BUT - there is no way to get info about the user to unsubscribe in
> iOS. This is not the plugin issue, but the iOS approach for the
> process. We should implement our own backend for security reasons (by
> the way Google also recommends to do the same, but still left the way
> to check the state directly from the app).
>
> So, after some researches, I found guys who made backend and plugin
> and it is free until you have less than 10 000 USD revenue for the
> month. https://www.revenuecat.com/
> https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter
>
> I've implemented this plugin in my apps and it works like a charm.
> There is some good approaches that allow you to get a subscription
> state at any point in the app. I'm going to make an example and
> article, but not sure about the timing.
>
> ==== UPDATE from 03.10.2019
>
> I recommend using new package from Flutter
> team  https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase
>
> The example with code is here https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase/example
>
> With this plugin I successfully implemented payments and recursive
> subscriptions to Android and iOS simultaneously. With the old package I
> had some minor issues.

You can use nice plugin [flutter_inapp_purchase](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase)

I've used it for the app that I developed and it works well. You can use my example of how to work with subscription - [github](https://github.com/awaik/flutter-examples/tree/master/in_app_purchase_subscription)
There is a complete working example - when you run it, you should get the screen

[image]

(do not forget to log in to Google play in an emulator or you will get “in-app billing version 3 NOT supported”)

Comment: can I run the github starter code on the emulator? Are there any specific changes that I would need to make in the google play developer console? Or is this run of the mill? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can run it, it should work without any changes. (do not forget to log in to Google play in emulator or you will get “in-app billing version 3 NOT supported”)

Comment: Newbie Question. Do I have to have a release ready apk and release the same on the google play . Is there a testing / internal dev way of doing this without releasing the app.

Comment: I usually test .apk file. So - I send it to myself and install on the devices (phones or tablets). After these preliminary tests I create release for Internal test track in Google play. 
Picture https://imgur.com/a/bEldKy8

Comment: So this was launched a 2 days ago -- https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase . I am looking at making use of this.. I hope this reduces the overhead to test . But thanks for your support thus far.

Comment: No, it was launched far more earlier. You've looked to the update date. Versions history is here https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase#-changelog-tab-

Comment: I tried running your example app on my emulator and physical device but it doesn't show the widget with the card.

Comment: Now I would recommend to use plugin from Flutter team  pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase 
So, try to use their example 
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/in_app_purchase/example
it works well. I switched to their package and it helped me to solve problems with payments on iOS.

Comment: @awaik do you make any tutorial for revenuecat? I try it on iOS working fine on android I cannot get any offerings

Comment: @EvripidesKyriacou Hi, sorry, have no time for this. The usual problem is the wrong settings. Check that you have made all credentials correctly
https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/creating-play-service-credentials

Comment: I tried it and I think I configured correct, this will be work on simulator or I have to published on a closed track?

Comment: ohh, it does NOT work on the simulator. But you can run the app on the real device from your IDE and it will work.

Comment: Hey sir, ty for this answer, regarding RevenueCat, we need to give them API access, is it secure?

Comment: Hi Lidor, they can't get your money or some sensitive data. But they get full info about purchases and products.
For me it's ok.

Comment: By the way,  it is a good question, you can ask their support and share with us.

Comment: is the new plugin totally free?

Comment: Plugin yes, but the cloud service free only up to 10000$ revenue per month.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for resource on how to implement IAP, Flutter team wrote a tutorial using [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package and Firebase as backend for validation.

Link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0

Answer (score -1):

Android and IOS both with `In-App-Purchase` with auto-renew working best and easy way in `Revenuecat` plugin Link https://docs.flutterflow.io/advanced-functionality/payments/revenuecat

Comment: How much tax deducted by revenuecat each transaction?