# Is there any way to add In App Purchases in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-web, in-app-subscription, flutter-desktop

I want to add google in app purchases in my flutter web and desktop project.
is there any way that we can do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement In-App Purchases Subscription in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880390/how-to-implement-in-app-purchases-subscription-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot do google iap in desktop app or web app. Because we dont have a store that link to desktop or web app. Like I make an application that runs on multiple platform android, web. In web we use stripe and in android we use google iap. To make payment synchronization in both of the applications (android and web) we ca use google pub/sub service and enable RTDN (real time developer notifications.). If any payment status changes it will trigger rtdn apis to notify changes.
Pub Sub:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview
RTDN:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference
See Section 11 in following code lab:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#10